# interrupted music can not be wake up in safari or other browsers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In my app ,i play my music in this way :

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
AVAudioPlayer *pl = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName] error:nil];
[pl play];
```

Now other music had been interrupt.After my music been played,i resume playback like this:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:nil];
```

It works perfect for me, when music played by some media player(as:QQ Player, iPhone's music, etc.);

But it was inefficacy, when the first music played by safari,chrome and so on.

How could i resume palyback?